# Regular expressions PHP and HTML pattern

Tags: php, html

The goal is to put into the HTML  pattern attribute the same regular expression of this PHP code regular expression.
So it's the same this pattern regular expression

```
pattern="[A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$"
```

to this?

```
if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$/i', $trimmed['first_name'])) {
...
```

Comment: What is an "HTML pattern"?

Comment: @tadman HTML allows a `pattern` attribute in `<input>` elements, the browser will automatically check that the entered value matches the regexp.

Comment: The only difference i can figure out is that on your PHP pattern you mark the start of the string (using ^) and on your HTML pattern the start of the pattern is not defined.

Comment: @LucianoGiordano HTML automatically anchors the pattern, you don't need to write it explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar If that's what this question is about that'd make sense, but the phrasing is far from clear.

Comment: He said "HTML pattern attribute". You don't parse that as "pattern attribute in HTML"?

Comment: The PHP is case insensitive (/i), so it will match [A-Za-z] while the HTML version isn’t. You could specify to match [A-Za-z] on your HTML version if it’s not possible to set the case insensitive flag.

Comment: The goal is to replace the regular expression in the PHP code with the same regular expression in the HTML using the pattern attribute. For example  when I am filling out a sign up form I'm checking name input in the HTML no need to check again in the PHP code.

Comment: Just an opinion, but it’s a good policy to check data server side too. Don’t trust browser or JavaScript validation as it could be easily bypassed by and XSS attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you are using in `PHP` uses the `insensitive` regex flag because of the `/i` at the end of the expression. Because of this it will not care about case. The expression in the pattern attribute will be concerned with case. Two make them the same you can do the following:

Case Insensitive:

```
 HTML 
 [A-Z a-z \'.-]{2,20}$

 PHP
 /^[A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$/i
```

Case Sensitive:

```
 HTML 
 [A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$

 PHP
 /^[A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP uses the `i` modifier, which makes it case-insensitive. There's no way to specify this modifier in the pattern, so you need to write both upper and lowercase `A-Za-z`

There's no need to escape `'` in HTML; that's only needed in PHP because this is being used to quote the string itself.

You don't need `$` in the HTML attribute. The pattern is automatically anchored at the beginning and end of the input.

So what you want is:

```html
<form>
<input pattern="[A-Za-z '.\-]{2,20}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve the same result using this regular expression: `pattern="[a-zA-Z '.-]{2,20}$"`